# PHP file_get_contents / CURL not returning full page

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I'm geting some strange behaviour trying to pull 3rd party file contents using CURL or  file_get_contents, pasrt of the page is read, but it stops at a random position... no error though (timeout etc).

Probably easiest to see if I give the full example!:

Using the following very bsic script to read a full URL and return the contents works just fine, with the full content of the page (less some external css etc) in a mater of a second or two:

```
<?php    
set_time_limit(180);
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.fantasyleague.com/Classic/Stats/playerlist.aspx?dpt=3');
echo $page;
?>
```

However, if we change to

```
<?php    
set_time_limit(180);
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.fantasyleague.com/Classic/Stats/playerlist.aspx?dpt=4');
echo $page;
?>
```

it takes ages to run, and eventually returns part of the page, but not all.  It's not consistent, but it generally ends with either "A Westwood AV 3.6 12" or "show", a bit further up the page.

If you look at the two URLs, you can see they are basically prettu much the same.  And this behaviour has onyl just started occuring, up until a day or two ago, both worked fine.

Any ideas?  I can provide any further info I've missed out!

Edit:

An example of where the file finishes... original file contains:

```
<div class="right">
    <a id="Playerlist_help_button" class="button left" href="#"><div>Show help</div></a>
    <a id="Playerlist_filters_button" class="button left" href="#"><div>Show filters</div></a>
    <a class="button left" href="PlayerListPrintable.aspx" target="_blank"><div>Printable Version</div></a>
    <br class="clear" />
</div>
```

but the retrieved data stops at:

```
<div class="right">
    <a id="Playerlist_help_button" class="button left" href="#"><div>Show help</div></a>
    <a id="Playerlist_filters_button" class="button left" href="#"><div>Show
```

or the other place it often fails is:

```
        <td><div class="chilli normal" /></td>


        <td>12</td>


        <td>0</td>
```

which becomes:

```
        <td><div class="chilli normal" /></td>


        <td>12</td>
```

Comment: Is it possible that there is Javascript on the page and parts of it are being retrieved via AJAX?

Comment: Strage, maxlen default is to read until end of file is reached.

Comment: I've tried to load the page with Ruby (timed out) and with Python (ends after "12"), so I guess it's something with the server

Answer (score 0):

by file_get_contents or curl At one time only you can get html source but not all components

Comment: What do you mean with: "not all components"? Web proxy's can handle these request without any problem. The only difference is that JavaScript in your browser can change the content. You don't know what user1943049 want to do with the content. So you don't know if any of these can get applied.

Comment: I don't think it is anything to do with javascript etc, looking at the position at which it stops... not sure how I can add code samples to a comment, but will update my original question...

Comment: Indeed, but PHP has enough bugs. There is a big chance that this in a bug. A while ago I had also a very stage problem. When I add a comment after a line of code than the code works. When I remove the comment, it doesn't work any more. You can try to update your PHP version, if that doesn't work you can apply a bug here: https://bugs.php.net/. Or you could wait a few day's, maybe someone here has a solution.

Comment: @Laurence A big chance? file_get_contents is used daily in thousands of applications worldwide. If there really was a bug in fetching data from a simple URL, it would be known by now. The much bigger chance is the OP doing something wrong, like not sending the proper headers or something like that.

Comment: @Gordon, that is true. But I think that it is very strange that you get 2 different results when you do exactly the same. It is also possible that the other site does something wrong. The problem could be everywhere.

Comment: @Laurence It's not exactly the same. Sure, it's GET request, but to two different URLs, so results may vary.

Comment: @Gordon Sorry, I thought it were results from the same URL.

Comment: @saeed you might want to delete your answer: first of all, it's nonsense and second, the OP said he tried cURL and got the same results, so your answer is not helping.

Comment: @Gordon, what do you mean about sending the wrong headers? The script I posted does absolutely nothing other than set the time limit, call file_get_contents and then echo the results, so I'm not sure where I could be doing anything wrong.  In my actual application, there is of course much more going on, but the problem is perfectly demonstrated in the two examples, one worknig and one not, give in the OP.  Feel free to try out the two scrips and observe the problem directly.

Comment: @A1Dan well, file_get_contents sends the [default headers of the HTTP Stream](http://php.net/manual/de/context.http.php). This is not the same as what the browser sends. For instance, the user_agent is usually empty and I have seen servers refuse to send data when it's missing. It doesn't apply in your case though. Like I said, I tried with PHP, Python and Ruby and the phenomenon occurs with all three which suggests something wrong on the server side. Easiest would be to contact them and ask.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah suspect it is server-side.  The problem is, without being able to tell them what I think is wrong, I'm not likely to get very far.... they won't be interested in just "there's something wrong with your page, I don't know what".  It's just so random the way it stops in the middle of a load of html - I coule understand if it was when it came to a certain tag or something, but it's in between tags that it stops.  I've checked for special characters etc, and there's nothing but space!

Comment: My suspicion remains taht it's some kind of time-out, given that it doesn't always stop at the same place.  If there was something specific on the page whihc was terminating the CURL, I would expect it to happen at the same point each time.  Also, as mentioned, the points at which it does stop contain no unusual characters or syntax - just space.  Equally though, if these functions time-out, I would expect an error / failure, rather than just partial loading of the page.  Baffled!

Comment: Before I start trying to work this out for myself (in case it's not possible), can anybody advise on whether a solution that checks how far it got and then retires, starting from that point sounds feesible?  There is a CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM option for CURL that I've never tried using...?