# cURL returns half json string in most cases

Tags: php, json, curl, wunderlist

`First edit (more details)`:

- I used Modify Headers plugin in Firefox and visited the page (http://api.wunderlist.com/me/tasks), this showed the full and correct json string that I need. It never fails (25+ tests)
- I tried using file_get_contents, but also file_get_contents cuts the response down. At various points.
- cURL does the same, cuts down the response json at various points. Looks "at random"

`Original post`:

I'm breaking my head on a strange issue here. I've created a PHP Wrapper for Wunderlist2 (http://www.wunderlist.com) which can be found here: https://github.com/PENDOnl/Wunderlist2-PHP-Wrapper

It worked perfectly until I was notified by a user that the class stopped working all of a sudden. Since I created a free service (http://wcal.me) to provide a calendar feed for Wunderlist users, I decided to take a look at that script since that's the most easy way for me to debug the script.

Login in to Wunderlist and fetching the authtoken works, also all other functions in the class seem to work find (getting 'me', 'me/lists', etc.) However, in case of the getTasks function ('me/tasks') the response that I get is not complete, it simply stops in the middle of a json string. Therefor the `json_decode` function returns NULL and thus no tasks will be available in the calender feed/method response.

I also noticed that it's pretty random, because in some cases (<10%) it works like it should, but after another refresh the output is cut in half again. Also, the exact location of the 'cut' is different per refresh.

Is there anyone that can identify what the problem is? I tried to see if there is a way to wait untill a complete download of the file before it is returned, but it would be strange if that wasn't the default behaviour of cURL. I also tried to increase the timeout time, but since it returns a value I guess it doesn't timeout either.

All code can be foundin the Github repo, so far this is the only part I've changed to debug:

```
        // get / put / delete requests should have HTTP Code 200 OK
        // only exception is the login method, which returns HTTP Code 200 OK
        if($httpCode == 200 && (strtolower($method) != 'post' || $action == '/login'))
        {
            $return = json_decode($output, true);

            if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == MY_IP) {
                if( is_null($return) ) {
                    echo "<b>Output of json_decode is null:</b><br><br>";
                    echo $output;   
                } else {
                    echo "<b>Output of json_decode os not null:</b><br><br>";
                    echo $output;   
                }
            }

            return $return;
        }
```

The full response should look like something similar to this:

`[{"assignee_id":null,"completed_at":null,"completed_by_id":null,"created_at":"2013-11-10T13:16:54Z"},{"assignee_id":null,"completed_at":null,"completed_by_id":null,"created_at":"2013-11-10T13:16:54Z"}]`

But instead in most cases it's:

`[{"assignee_id":null,"completed_at":null,"completed_by_id":null,"created_at":"2013-11-10T13:16:54Z"},{"assignee`

Of course, this is a minified response, there is more information in the response available and there are many more items in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with Wunderlist, just waiting for their fix :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I'm not sure if you noticed, but I'm the author of this question. And this _IS_ the answer to this question as it was no bug in PHP, Server configuration, json_decode or the cURL part of the code. It was purely on Wunderlist's side.

Answer (score 1):

For testing purposes, if you authenticate with the class, what result does browsing to http://api.wunderlist.com/me/tasks yield?

Also I'm sure you've already fixed but in base.class.php, $action is being checked for empty values twice instead of $action & $method.

Comment: Thanks, I modified the class on Github. Browsing to that page does not work, at least, without setting set a custom header (`authorization: Bearer TOKEN_HERE`) holding the token.

Comment: Just tried to do so using the Modify Headers plugin for firefox, but it keeps saying I'm not authenticated.

Comment: Bummer! Perhaps it could have something to do with server configuration and timing out somewhere. From the looks of it /me/tasks responses can become quite large. Does the error still occur when there is a small amount of tasks?

Comment: Some additional thoughts: To rule out that it is not the fault of Wunderlist, try and recreate error in Wunderlist2ApiJS or wunderlistpy.

I may be a bug with cURL, try and temporarily replace cURL with file_get_contents.

Comment: Will do, thanks for thinking along :) It does become quiet large, there are a lot of fields per task. But I can't remember having less tasks for a while and no user ever complained so far.. but you never know!

Comment: Good luck with it! Report back when you find the solution :)

Comment: I got the Modify Headers working, I forgot to decode my database string using the private key which is used to store user details. Stupid!

The page at api.wunderlist.com yields exactly what it is supposed to (every time), a full json string. So there's an issue with the curl request somewhere..

Comment: file_get_contents also cuts down the response at random places and occasionally shows the full string

Comment: Mmm very interesting. I did a search and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123378/php-file-get-contents-curl-not-returning-full-page.

They seemed to have a similar problem and suggested it may be a server configuration issue. Has your host done any automated updating or similar recently? Are you able to test on a different server?

Comment: It's my own server, but I've got to kick my system administrator since server configuration is not my cup of tea;-) We'll dive into it and let you know

Comment: Wunderlist just replied to my tweet, it's a bug on their side.

Comment: Some resolvement! Great to hear, well, when the services comes back online anyway :)

Curious that the API worked perfectly when accessed in-browser.

Comment: Yep, just tried it another 10-15 times. But all responses where complete json strings.